# debugging actionscript/flex app options

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I'm not sure of the proper term to describe what I wan to do.

I'm working on a Flex app.  It depends on a php based web service running in the same web server.

Right now, I'm using the free version of FDT.  It will not let my app access the php web service while running in the SWF (FDT's built in Flex app viewer).

I'd really like to be able to step thru my Flex app in a debugger.  So I need an IDE that will let me run a Flex app that accesses an outside web service.

A co-worker told me that IntelliJ supports this.  I'd like to know if there are any options - Eclipse, NetBeans anything else.

Mark

Comment: Flash Builder and IntelliJ both support full debugging

Comment: @Lee - awesome!  do you know of any others?

Comment: They're the main ones. Other than FDT, i can only think of Amethyst. I would suggest sticking with Flash Builder or IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

i ultimately settled on FDT.  i lost stepwise debugging but Firefox + web console and I've been able to do everything I need to.